# If I handcraft SAML2 SP metadata , how do I sign it?

Tags: jboss, metadata, saml-2.0, sign

First of all I have spent considerable time searching this site for the specific questions I have. So in case you find this duplicate , it means I could not locate those so pls share the link.

I have to set up an SP in an IdP(Siteminder) initiated SAML2 post binding in JBOSS EAP 6 and picket link.I am asked to provide metadata.I found [this site](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php) where I could plug in values and get the meta Data.

1 ] Now if I want to sign SPSSODescriptor in the metadata XML , how do I do it ? I cant use the public site to encrypt a production file.

2] Also would you know of an enterprise standard mechanism of generating SP metadata and sign them ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do from PicketLink (already some discussions available from other forums).

You can sign the metadata using JDK Security API or other Java Security API and place the generated signature in metadata between `<Signature>Signature elements</Signature>`.

Other easy solution is: (didn't try this before, but seems worth to try)

1. Generate metadata by from [SAML-Tool site](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php) and save it.
2. Download XMLSec Tool from [Shibboleth site](http://shibboleth.net/downloads/tools/xmlsectool/latest).
3. Unzip and run xmlsectool.sh as follows,

`$ xmlsectool.sh --sign --inFile <LOCATION_OF_METADATA_TO_BE_SIGNED> --outFile <TO_BE_LOCATION_OF_SIGNED_METADATA> --keystore <LOCATION_OF_JKS_KEYSTORE> --keystorePassword <JKS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD> --key <PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS> --keyPassword <PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD>`

Comment: would you have windows version of xmlsectool ?

Comment: And could you provide the link to your blog where you listed the code to sign it ?